# Possible to change style of password reset page

Tags: password

Is it possible to change how the password reset box appears when a user requests a password reset? Ideally we would like to include the same functionality but within a page that we have control over so that it looks like the same website users are used to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [setPasswordPath](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#setPasswordPath) config setting to a template in your `craft/templates` folder and you style the page however you want.

The form itself would need to be similar to the "[Set Password Form](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/set-password-form)" template example in the docs.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! What would need to be done for the form itself? Would it suffice to just start with what exists in `craft/app/templates/setpassword.html`? It doesn't look like that form defines an action unless I'm blind. Would I have to point it to a specific action?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Brad, I'm running into an issue. We want the set password form to include both a password field and a "confirm password" field, which I want to validate in a custom controller. However, even when I have the hidden action input in the form set to my custom controller, the controller that gets run is always users/setpassword. I think this is due to the URL of the form page. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I've created a new password set form in my templates folder and updated the setPasswordPath using the following in `config/general.php` but it's still pointing to the standard page. Any ideas?

`return array(
    'setPasswordPath' => 'user/set-password'
);`